# How to color a cell based on the colors in a row with conditional formatting or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image] I'm trying to color column A (The Ys) based on the rows 1-6. I want it so if it is both green and red to turn yellow, just green to turn green, and just red to turn red. The picture shows the basic idea of what I want.

I'm unaware of any condtional formatting formulas that could make this possible currently. I've scoutted this site on info on VBA and trying to learn it for this. If you can solve this can you please explain each step so I can understand it better for the future.

Comment: I know you can make a cell's formatting conditional upon values in other cells. If this is of interest, let me know and I can help you through it. It sounds like what you're trying to do is make the formatting of one cell conditional on the FORMATTING of other cells. I don't know a way to do this - and I don't believe a way exists to do this - but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, there is a way to do this with Conditional formatting, but that uses a little-known trick that Excel has: the `GET.CELL` function ([more info](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/info-only-get-cell-arguments.20611/)).

This function cannot be used in a cell, but it can be used in a named range, so the idea is to create a named range, give it a name like "BackgroundColorIndex" and define it like this:

```
=GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))
```

[image]

You can then create a sheet named "Color" where you define your colors:

[image]

Where each Index is determined by using the `BackgroundColorIndex` function.

[image]

I would then suggest to create named ranges for each color (GreenIndex, YellowIndex and RedIndex), so we can refer to them later.

Now, we are going to need to create another version of `BackgroundColorIndex`, but instead of referring to the cell itself, it will always refer to the corresponding cell in the sheet where you have your data.

Let's call it `BackgroundColorIndexSheet1` with the following definition:

```
=GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("Sheet1!rc",FALSE))
```

(Note that you need to replace "Sheet1" with the name of your sheet.)

[image]

Then, you would create a new sheet. Let's call it "Sheet2". It will be where we do the calculations.

It that sheet, column A and headers would be identical to Sheet1, but the formulas inside would be `=BackgroundColorIndexSheet1`

For instance, in my case, I have the following values.

[image]

And we can then add a few helper columns that will look like this:
[image]

The formulas :

- J2: `=SUMIF(B2:G2,">0")/MAX(COUNTIF(B2:G2,">0"),1)`
- K2: `=IF(J2=GreenIndex,GreenIndex,0)`
- L2 : `=IF(J2=Redindex,RedIndex,0)`
- M2: `=IF(SUM(K2:L2)>0,SUM(K2:L2),IF(J2>0,YellowIndex,0))`

Now we can use the values in the output column in our conditional formatting rules. For instance:

[image]

And the outcome would be :

[image]

⚠ You will need to press F9 to refresh the calculations when values change.
⚠ You will need to save your workbook as .xlsm since we are using `GET.CELL`